# Информационные блоки. Взаимодействие

Tags: битрикс

На каком уровне происходит взаимодействие инфоблоков в 1с битриксе? 
Например у одного блока есть привязка к нескольким другим и необходимо чтобы при изменении значения какого нибудь свойства менялось  значение свойства других инфоблоков.

Это делается на уровне модулей? Нужно создавать модули и классы-сущности которые используют апи других модулей? Мне мало документации, где просто стрелочками показано что мол модули и компоненты связаны между собой.

Я очень не люблю когда все в куче, и без комментариев, как в битриксе.

Нужно разобраться в проекте.

[[@binliz](/users/8664/binliz)](/users/8664/binliz), хорошо спасибо, просто неясно где вызывать эти функции , в init.php, опять же этот ивент будет один для всех инфоблоков?  Что неправильного в этом?

Comment: подниму...

Comment: ни у кого нет никаких идей?

Answer (score 1):

Прям пальцем в небо.
Тип инфоблока - сущность которая определяет следующие параметры:
привязка к сайту, тип данных, возможность древовидной структуры.
Инфоблок - имеет привязку к типу разпределяется на секции и элементы инфоблока.
И секции и элементы имеют возможность кроме стандартных полей быть дополненными неограниченным количеством доп. свойств.
Дополнительные свойства имеют свои типы: текст, картинка, файл, дата, число, привязка к секциям, привязка к элементам инфоблока... ну и еще куча пишу примерно - можно рассширять до бесконечности.
Для работы с элементами инфоблока и своствами есть у битрикса АПИ.

Я конечно не совсем понял постановку вопроса но если ее трактовать так:
Нужно при смене одного свойства менять другие свойства.

Тогда. Нужно в файле init.php создать обработчик события OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate ну или OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd и в нем уже с помощью ваших манипуляций изменить приходящий массив данных. После чего битрикс сам обработает массив и добавит или изменит нужные свойства.

Ну это я так в кратце. Если более конкретно зададите вопрос, я смогу более конкретно ответить. И вообще у битрикса неплохое сообщество которое достаточно быстро поможет вам найти правильные решения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я знаю что инфоблок имеет разные типы свойств. Вот есть привязка к элементам. Даже с автозаполнением, окей, это хорошо. Привязал я к определенному элементу, теперь при вводе  свойства наример числа какого-то, изменилось и свойство определенное в связанном элементе по определенной формуле просчиталось , где это реализовывать? OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd , это что для всех инфоблоков вместе, как определять где какой тип, по коду? В одной такой функции или их будет много разных и файлов типа init.php?

Comment: Непонятно как именно писать этот обработчик OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd  для всех классов

Comment: Надо читать Апи при чем срочно, так вы мало разберетесь. 
init.php лежит в папочке bitrix/php_interface/
для разных сайтов он может быть разным и в частности если существует 2 сайта с разной логикой то в папке php_interface появляются двухбуквенные подпапки типа s2 (lang_id) сайта и его init.php

Орпеделять по чему угодно по ид, коду...
Событий можно вешать сколько угодно, но по моему у вас тут этого вообще делать не надо.

Расскажите какие мамипуляции и где производятся с инфоблоком. В админке или во фронтенде?

Comment: В админке, надо связать два свойства разных инфоблоков, при изменении одного , чтобы менялся другой. 

Сайт один, инфоблоков много, для всех инфоблоков одна функция что ли?

Comment: можно более наглядно - что надо сделать. К примеру есть одно поле если я его меняю то в этом же элементе меняется другое по формуле. 

Или так есть 2 элемента связанные одним полем, при обновлении данных в одном из них меняются данные во втором.

Comment: Все правильно в одном инфоблоке есть привязка в другом, при изменении свойства (например, свойство список статус опубликован, чтобы в связанном увеличилось свойство число кол. на единицу) чтобы обновлялось свойство в связанном. Как еще конкретней сказать?:)

Comment: Тогда проще сказать что у вас неправильно организованна структура магазина но ок
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getproperty.php

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/setpropertyvaluecode.php

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockpropertyupdate.php

Этих 3х ссылок вполне достаточно чтобы решить вашу задачу.